# How to check Server down with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

I want to check Server down with VB.net. but I don't understand about network please help me how to check server down with VB.net

Answer (score 4):

You could do a ping to that computer.

```
Dim _ping As New Ping
Dim _pingreply = _ping.Send(IpAddress, 2000)
If _pingreply.Status = IPStatus.Success Then
  'server is online
Else
  'server is offline
End If
```

Of course this will only work if the server allows pings. And will only give you so much information. Consider it a first step.

You need to be careful to set the timeout to an appropriate value. In this case I set it to 2000 milliseconds, which might not be long enough in your case. But the longer you set it the longer the user will have to wait before he knows it is online.